# Is there any way to alias ";;" to "ll"?

Tags: bash, alias

I am a huge fan of aliases. this feature REALLY makes my life easier.
I have the following alias set:
`alias ll="ls-lah"`

However, I frequently fatfinger `ll` to `;;`
As a solution, I attempted to alias `;;` to `"ls-lah"`
However, the `;;` characters are not accepted in the .bash_aliases file as legitimate input.
Similarly, I have tried `\;\;` but still no love.

Is there a way to alias the input `;;` ?

Comment: No, the semicolon has a reserved syntactic meaning as the command separator.

Comment: For what it's worth, functions are superior to aliases in basically every way.

Comment: Because it's open-source, (in theory), you could recompile Bash and hard-code said alias in. IDK if that's possible. But it certainly isn't _practical_ (too much work). Instead, I'd suggest just practicing and getting used to doing it properly TBH.

Comment: I aliased `öö` to `ll` on my german keyboard for the same reason, this works ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> alias ';;'="ls -lah"
bash: alias: `;;': invalid alias name
```

Thus, bash does not allow creating this alias. So the answer to current question is: "no, there is no way to alias ";;" to "ll"?". `;` is a reserved character in sh and bash to separate different commands on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it, and following are working,

`$ alias ..="ls -lrth"`

`$ alias .,="ls -lrth"`

`$ alias ,="ls -lrth"`

`$ alias ?="ls -lrth"`

`$ alias +="ls -lrth"`

`$ alias ~="ls -lrth"`

`$ alias ?="ls -lrth"`

`$ alias !="ls -lrth"`

`$ alias @="ls -lrth"`

Comment: None of these were requested, though. The request was for an alias using `;;` 

Comment: Till that, I didn't find any solution for it...if you will find any please share